# Listen to route changes (Next v.13 app directory)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

Pre Next v.13 (app dir) you could do something like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChangeComplete = () => {
      methodToCall()
    }

    // Add the event listener for 'routeChangeComplete'
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChangeComplete)

    // Clean up the event listener on unmount
    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChangeComplete)
    }
  }, [triggEffect])
```

But the .events prop does not exist on the v.13 router that's imported via ('next/navigation').

I have animated a 100vh nav menu with framer-motion, and I want to make sure that the closing animation is not triggered until a route change is completed.

I believe in Next v.13 an alternative would be to use the usePathName hook:

```
  const pathname = usePathname()

  useEffect(() => {
    methodToCall()
  }, [pathname, methodToCall])
```

But that doesn't work for me (the method is not triggered).