# Detect navigation event before it happens nextjs 13 app router, then prevent it from happening

Tags: events, navigation, router, next.js13, onbeforeunload

With nextjs 12 (pages router) the router returned from 'next/router' had navigation events you could listen for and handle appropriately. [Here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#routerevents) is the documentation.

One specific event is `routeChangeStart`. When you want prompt a user before they leave a page you have listen for that event, then open a modal and throw an error to prevent navigation.

With nextjs 13 (app router) the router returned from 'next/navigation' does not have the same ability to subscribe to events.

There is a solution in the documentation to tell when a route has already changed. It uses the two new hooks

- `usePathname`
- `useSearchParams`

[Here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#router-events) is that solution.

I want to know ***BEFORE*** a route is about to change.

How do you know when a nextjs 13 app (using the app router) is about to navigate, and how do you prevent it from doing so?

Comment: This might not be possible, many are asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76980849/catching-global-route-changes-in-nextjs-13 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77296306/next-js-version-13-router-events-deprecated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76773884/listen-to-route-changes-next-v-13-app-directory and no answer yet replicates previous functionality. I also found nothing in the github issues. This is pretty common functionality, I'm genuinely surprised I haven't found an out of the box solution yet.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the Link component for the naviation, you can switch it with a custom component and use the useRouter hook.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Shahryar_Jahanshahloo. I think a custom link component that uses the `useRouter` hook is a good solution if every thing is navigable by links. Unfortunately in a web browser this is not true. Nextjs 12 router events take into account navigation from the browser back and forward buttons. I'm looking for a solution that handles both scenarios

Answer (score -1):

To detect Navigate Event before it happens I use the hook usePathname + useRef + useEffect in the `NavigationEvents` ([Link from Nextjs13](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#examples))

My below code is checking if user navigate off `/about`

```js
export function NavigationEvents() {

    // Get the current pathname from the router
    const pathname = usePathname()
    
    // Create a ref to store the previous pathname
    const ref = useRef(pathname)
    
    useEffect(() => {
    // Check if the pathname has changed and if the previous pathname was '/page'
    if (ref.current !== pathname &&
        ref.current === '/about') { 
        // Do something before the page changes
        // For example, you could show a confirmation dialog or save some data
    }
    
    // Update the ref to store the current pathname
    ref.current = pathname
    }, [pathname])
    
    // Return null because this component doesn't render any UI elements
    return null
}
```

Note: The `NavigationEvents` have to be add to Root layout for properly working (not child page layout)

[image: reference photo]

Comment: Hey @truongthi-bic, thanks for your answer. So I tested your solution and the `useEffect` is running after the page change. So it works for an effect after the pathname change which is great, but I am looking for a solution that tells me right before the route changes and the page renders.

Answer (score -1):

Credit goes to [Steven Linn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2100569/steven-linn?tab=profile) ([github](https://github.com/stevenlafl))

**Note: This is only the solution to the FIRST part of the question. That is "How do you know when a nextjs 13 app (using the app router) is about to navigate?"** I do not believe this solution can be used to prevent navigating away. Additionally, it does not work with the back and forward buttons. But a half solution is better than no solution so here I am.

I ran into this problem but for next 14.1.0. The way I was able to listen for a route change before it occurred was by referencing [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/41934#discussioncomment-6459723) github comment. They recommend using their [nextjs13-router-events package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs13-router-events).

But seeing I needed this for next 14.1.0, I took my own (similar) steps. In summary:

- Copy paste the components' code from `RouteChangeProvider`, `Link`, and `useRouteChange`.
- Change all `import Link from "next/link";` to `import Link from "path/to/custom/Link";`
- Wrap your app with the `RouteChangeProvider`

```
import { RouteChangeProvider } from './RouteChangeProvider';
...
return (
  <RouteChangeProvider>
    {children}
  </RouteChangeProvider>
)
```

- Use the hook in the components where you need to listen for route changes:

```
import useRouteChange from './useRouteChange';
...
export default function Component(props: any) {
  ...
  useRouteChange({
    onRouteChangeStart: () => {
      console.log('Put code here to run BEFORE route changes');
    },
    onRouteChangeComplete: () => {
      console.log('onComplete 3');
    }
  });
  ...
}
```

- **(Additional step for next 14.1.0)** In the `Link.tsx` component, move the `const { onRouteChangeStart } = useRouteChangeContext();` line above the `if (!useLink) return <a href={href} onClick={onClick} {...rest} />;`

```
  if (!useLink) return <a href={href} onClick={onClick} {...rest} />;

  const { onRouteChangeStart } = useRouteChangeContext();
```

becomes

```
  const { onRouteChangeStart } = useRouteChangeContext();

  if (!useLink) return <a href={href} onClick={onClick} {...rest} />;
```

- **(Additional step for next 14.1.0)** In the `RouteChangeProvider.tsx`, add `onRouteChangeComplete` to the dependency of the useEffect using it.

```
useEffect(() => onRouteChangeComplete(), [pathname, searchParams]);
```

becomes

```
useEffect(() => onRouteChangeComplete(),[pathname, searchParams, onRouteChangeComplete]);
```

P.S. The last two steps were a hotfix for an error and warning I received when creating the production build.

Answer (score -2):

```
"use client";
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "../../css/loader.css";

export default function Loader() {
  const path = usePathname();
  const params = useSearchParams();
  const loaderRef = useRef(null);

  if (loaderRef?.current) {
    loaderRef.current.classList.remove("loading-bar-end");
    loaderRef.current.classList.add("loading-bar-start");
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaderRef?.current) {
      loaderRef.current.classList.remove("loading-bar-start");
      loaderRef.current.classList.add("loading-bar-end");
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="fixed z-[50] top-0 w-full">
      <div
        ref={loaderRef}
        className="z-[50] bg-danger pb-1 rounded-full loading-bar-start"
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Its actually very simple!  I think their documentation makes it a
> little bit confusing but what is happening here is when you use Link
> or useRouter to navigate, the usePathname captures the path of the
> route without the route actually loading so you can perform like the
> start of the loading here and then in the useEffect you can stop the
> loading (using CSS animations or whatever you like). The dependencies
> for the useEffect can either be [path, params (useSearchParams*)] or
> nothing.Totally depends on you! Similary its the same for useSearchParams!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).