# Next Js version 13 router.events deprecated

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need a help since the router events in version 13 of nextJs are deprecated I wanted a help in the code below.I am creating a pop up when the user hits tries to navigate to another route.So can anyone help me with this?

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import React, { useState, useEffect,useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import { Modal } from "../Modal/Modal";
import { ExclamationIcon, XIcon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import { Dialog } from "@headlessui/react";
import {usePathname, useSearchParams} from 'next/navigation'
import { useNavigationEvent } from './useNavigationEvent';



export interface serviceProps {
  shouldConfirmLeave: boolean;
  updateParent: (...args: any[]) => any;
  title: string;
  subTitle: string;
  content?: string;
}

export const PromptDialog = ({
  updateParent,
  shouldConfirmLeave,
  title,
  subTitle,
  content,
}: serviceProps): React.ReactElement<serviceProps> => {
  const [showPromptDialog, setshowPromptDialog] = useState(false);
  const [nextRouterPath, setNextRouterPath] = useState<string>();

  const router = useRouter();

  //implementing a test feature.
  const pathname=usePathname();
  const searchParams=useSearchParams();
  // ends here

  const routeChangeStart = useCallback(
    (nextPath: string) => {
      if (!shouldConfirmLeave) {
        return;
      }
      console.log("Hello")
      console.log({ nextPath });
      updateParent("initial");
      setshowPromptDialog(true);
      setNextRouterPath(nextPath);
      // need to throw error to trick router
      // look for better solution in the future

      // Commented out since it was causing an error.And in version 13 events are deprecate
      // router.events.emit("routeChangeError");
      throw "Aborting route change. Please ignore this error.";
    },
    [shouldConfirmLeave],
  );

  const cancelRouteChange = () => {
    updateParent("cancel");
    setNextRouterPath(undefined);
    setshowPromptDialog(false);
  };

  const confirmRouteChange = () => {
    updateParent("confirm");
    setshowPromptDialog(false);
    // removeListener();
    if (nextRouterPath) router.push(nextRouterPath);
  };

  // const removeListener = () => {
  //   router.events.off("routeChangeStart", routeChangeStart);

  // };

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("hi")
    console.log(pathname)
    const url=`${pathname}${searchParams}`;
    console.log(url)
  },[pathname,searchParams,routeChangeStart])

  useEffect(() => {
    // router.events.on("routeChangeStart", routeChangeStart);
    // return removeListener;
  }, [routeChangeStart]);

  return (
    <Modal open={showPromptDialog} onClose={cancelRouteChange}>
      <div className="hidden sm:block absolute top-0 right-0 pt-4 pr-4">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="bg-neutral-900 text-neutral-400 hover:text-neutral-500 focus:outline-none"
          onClick={cancelRouteChange}
        >
          <span className="sr-only">Close</span>
          <XIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="sm:flex sm:items-start">
        <div className="mx-auto flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-gradient-to-r from-orange-400 to-pink-600 sm:mx-0 sm:h-10 sm:w-10">
          <ExclamationIcon
            className="h-6 w-6 text-white-600 "
            aria-hidden="true"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
          <Dialog.Title
            as="h3"
            className="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-white"
          >
            {title}
          </Dialog.Title>
          <div className="mt-2">
            <p className="text-sm text-neutral-500">{subTitle}</p>
            {content && (
              <p className="text-sm text-neutral-500 mt-2">{content}</p>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-5 sm:mt-4 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
        <button
          className="ml-4 primary-button"
          type="button"
          disabled={false}
          onClick={confirmRouteChange}
        >
          Continue without saving
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="rounded-md mt-3 w-full inline-flex justify-center border border-neutral-300 shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-white text-base font-medium text-neutral-700 hover:text-neutral-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm"
          onClick={cancelRouteChange}
        >
          Keep editing
        </button>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

I tried all the above methods.I tried using the useNavigation hook which was **[[Next 13] router.events removed?](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/42016#top)**#42016 mentioned in this but couldn't solve it . Please try to solve this issue.

```
Source
components/PromptService/PromptService.tsx (39:36) @ pathname

  37 | const useNavigationEvent = (onPathnameChange: () => void) => {
  38 |   // Save pathname on component mount into a REF
> 39 |   const savedPathNameRef = useRef(pathname);
     |                                  ^
  40 |   useEffect(() => {
  41 |     // If REF has been changed, do the stuff
  42 |     if (savedPathNameRef.current !== pathname) {
```

```
Source
components/PromptService/PromptService.tsx (39:36) @ pathname

  37 | const useNavigationEvent = (onPathnameChange: () => void) => {
  38 |   // Save pathname on component mount into a REF
> 39 |   const savedPathNameRef = useRef(pathname);
     |                                  ^
  40 |   useEffect(() => {
  41 |     // If REF has been changed, do the stuff
  42 |     if (savedPathNameRef.current !== pathname) {
```

```
components/PromptService/PromptService.tsx (39:36) @ pathname

  37 | const useNavigationEvent = (onPathnameChange: () => void) => {
  38 |   // Save pathname on component mount into a REF
> 39 |   const savedPathNameRef = useRef(pathname);
     |                                  ^
  40 |   useEffect(() => {
  41 |     // If REF has been changed, do the stuff
  42 |     if (savedPathNameRef.current !== pathname) {
```

```
components/PromptService/PromptService.tsx (39:36) @ pathname

  37 | const useNavigationEvent = (onPathnameChange: () => void) => {
  38 |   // Save pathname on component mount into a REF
> 39 |   const savedPathNameRef = useRef(pathname);
     |                                  ^
  40 |   useEffect(() => {
  41 |     // If REF has been changed, do the stuff
  42 |     if (savedPathNameRef.current !== pathname) {
```